# Filter ForeignKey id From Django Models

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I want to get data from some fields in a `Foriegnkey` that belongs to a particular `id`. But I can;t figure out how to make it work. I have two models;

```
class Tick(models.Model):
   user=models.ForeignKey(User)
   event_name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
   ticket_quantity=models.PositiveIntegerField(max_length=50, null=True,  blank=True,help_text='Optional, if you have unlimited ticket')
   ticket_plan_name_a=models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
   ticket_plan_price_a=models.PositiveIntegerField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name="Price",help_text='ticket price.')
   ticket_plan_name_b=models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
   ticket_plan_price_b=models.PositiveIntegerField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name="Price1",help_text='ticket price.')
```

Another Models

```
class BuyTick(models.Model):
    user=models.ForeignKey(User)
    tik=models.ForeignKey(Tick)
    tiket_qty=models.PositiveIntegerField(max_length=100)
    pub_date=models.DateTimeField()
    full_name=models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.tiket

class BuyTickForm(forms.ModelForm):
    tik=forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Tick.objects.get(pk=tick_id))

    class Meta:
        model=BuyTick
```

After trying the above codes out I got

> NameError: name 'tick_id' not defined

How can I get a particular tick_id from models Tick so as to display certain fields in the BuyTick form?

Update: For the views

```
def purchase_ticket(request, tikid):
    if request.method=="POST":
        form=BuyTickForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            data=form.cleaned_data
            newbuy=BuyTick(
                user=request.user,
                tik=Ticket.objects.get(pk=tikid),
                tiket_qty=data['tiket_qty'],
                full_name=data['full_name'],
                phone_no=data['phone_no'],
                pub_date=datetime.datetime.now())
            newbuy.save()
            return HttpResponse('Your ticket have been booked')
        else:
            print form.errors
    else:
        return render_to_response('buytickform.html',{'BuyTickForm':BuyTickForm,'post':Tick.objects.all().get(id=tikid)},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Template

```
<p> Event Name: {{post.event_name}} </p>

<form action="." method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}

         {{BuyTickForm.as_p}} 

      <input type="submit"  class="radbutton radorange" value="Confirm Ticket"/> 

    </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

First your model could use a couple of tweaks:

```
class BuyTick(models.Model):
    . . .
    tiket_qty=models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0, max_length=100)
    pub_date=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    . . .

    def __unicode__(self):
        # not sure what you're returning here...
        return self.tiket
```

You need to pass in the id to filter on when you instantiate the form, and you can also pass in the user from the request, which you can set automatically:

```
class BuyTickForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.tikid = kwargs.pop('tikid')
        self.user = kwargs.pop('user')
        super(BuyTickForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    tik=forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Tick.objects.filter(id=self.tikid))

    class Meta:
        model=BuyTick

    def save(self, commit=True):
        buy_tick = super(BuyTickForm, self).save(commit=False)
        buy_tick.user = self.user
        if commit:
            buy_tick.save()
        return buy_tick
```

You need to `filter()` the `Tick` objects instead of using `get`, otherwise you'll be returning more than one object, which will raise an exception when using `.get()`.

The view could use some love:

```
def purchase_ticket(request, tikid):
    tick = get_object_or_404(Tick, id=tikid)
    form = BuyTickForm(request.POST or None, tikid=tikid, user=request.user)

    if request.method == 'POST' and form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        # note that these fields don't exist on your model:
        #     full_name, phone_no
        # return something here... a redirect probably

    else:
        return render(request, 'buytickform.html',
            {'tick': tick, 'form': form})
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I'm getting Namerror: name 'self' not defined.

Comment: Make sure you're using double underscores before and after `init`

Comment: I did that. I wrote __init__ and I'm still getting nameerror.

Comment: Are you sure you're getting the name error in that class? That's most definitely the correct syntax to use. Here's a sample class: https://gist.github.com/alsoicode/1dc25196f61bf90ba06e which you can paste into the editor at: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_python_online.php and see the output, which is fundamentally the same as your `ModelForm`

Comment: Thanks I've fixed it. Now in the template, I'm getting KeyError: tick_id

Comment: Can you please add your template code to your question?

Comment: I've done that, kindly look at it. P:S might be slow to reply, my pc battery is flat need to charge. Will be back soon.

Comment: You're not passing the `tickid` to the form in your view, nor are you instantiating a form for the case when the request is a `GET`. If you instantiate your form in the manner from my example *before* the check for `request.method == 'POST'` it should work.

Comment: In your context, which I would refactor btw, you're passing the form class *itself* - not an instance of the class.

Comment: You're also trying to set fields on your `BuyTick` model that don't exist, and needlessly duplicating the functionality of the ModelForm.

Comment: Thanks so much for the explanation. After going through the code, it seems the reply is diverting from my plan. My plan is to get "tiket plan names and codes" from 'Tick' models through 'BuyTick' models in order to display it in the BuyTickForm for users to select the 'ticket plans and price' and complete their purchase. Hope you get the idea?

Comment: I think you need to re-state your question, or close this question and ask a new one.